# HTML file did not want to link with css NOT because of wrong placement of file

Tags: html, css, file

I recently create a little project to create a simple calculator. however, I can't connect my HTML into the CSS file. I have check the location of the file and the name of the css everything is correct. anyone know why it can't link up?

I named my html file as index.html and I named my css file as stylsheet.css

here is my file location:

[screenshot of my file location][1]

here are the codes I use in this project

the html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Kalkulator</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="css" href="stylesheet.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="calculator">
    <input type="text" name="calculator-screen" value="0" disabled>
    <div class="calculator-keys">
        <div class="row">
            <button class="all-clear">AC</button>
            <button class="precentage">%</button>
            <button class="operator" value="/">&divide;</button>
        </div>  
        <div class="row">
            <button class="number" value="7">7</button>
            <button class="number" value="8">8</button>
            <button class="number" value="9">9</button>
            <button class="operator" value="*">&time;</button>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <button class="number" value="4">4</button>
            <button class="number" value="5">5</button>
            <button class="number" value="6">6</button>
            <button class="operator" value="-">-</button>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <button class="number" value="1">1</button>
            <button class="number" value="2">2</button>
            <button class="number" value="3">3</button>
            <button class="operator" value="+">+</button>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <button class="number zero-btn" value="0">0</button>
            <button class="decimal" value="0">.</button>
            <button class="equal-sign">=</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

The CSS code:

```
.calculator {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-top: 200px;
    width: 400px;
}

.calculator-screen {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #252525;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: right; 
    font-size: 36px;
    border: none;
    padding: 0 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.calculator-keys {
    width: 100%;
}

.row {
    display: flex;
}

button{
    height: 80px;
    background-color: gray;
    border: 1px solid black;
    font-size: 32px;
    color: #fff;
    width: 25%;
    outline: none;
}

all-clear, .zero-btn {
    width: 50%
}

.operator, .equalsign {
    background-color: orange;
}

button:hover {
    background-color: darkgrey;
}

.operator:hover, .equalsign:hover {
    background-color: darkorange;
}
```

any help is a welcome, thank you~

Comment: Try opening your stylesheet.css with your browser and refreshing it.

Comment: Your recent edit should be to your answer. You've responded to a comment on your answer in the question.

Answer (score -1):

**Solved!** it looks like I use the incorrect code

the incorrect code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="css" href="stylesheet.css">
```

it should be:

```
<link href="stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

still not sure why, but it might be caused due to different type of html version I use (assumption)

EDIT:
For some of you that said it makes no different.

this is the web view if I use the supposedly the "wrong" line of html:
[`<link rel="stylesheet" type="css" href="stylesheet.css">`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FbJ6B.png)

This is the web view if I use the correct line of html :
[`<link href="stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet">`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6zMyJ.png)

As I said, I don't know why but it shows a plain html if i'm using the code line based on the picture 2. but it shows the css file if I'm using the code line based on the picture 3.

Comment: How in the world would `kalkulator.css` work if the file is named `stylesheet.css`?

Comment: It makes no difference in which order you place an element's attributes

Comment: I recently change the file name (pardon me).  I edited it so it'll not make any confusion to others

Comment: The order of the attributes didn't fix the problem, the "type" attribute did it: when present, it must be a MIME type that represent the type of style sheet, in your case it should be `type="text/css"`, and that is the default value when you omit the attribute.